# onmouseenter flickering tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to display a tooltip when hovering over a svg rect but the tooltip keeps on flickering, switching between display: none and display: flex erratically and unpredictably.

When I used the same code but hovered over a div the result was very smooth, so it seems to be related to the rect element.

I get different behaviours in the snippet below than I do when I open the HTML in Chrome.
In the snippet it seems to work if i enter the rect from left to right or top to bottom, but not the other way around.
In Chrome it just keeps flickering which ever direction I enter.

**Why is it behaving this way and what can I do about it?**

```js
const tooltips = document.querySelectorAll('.tooltip');
const bars = document.querySelectorAll('rect');

document.addEventListener('mousemove', fn);

function fn(e) {
  tooltips[0].style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
  tooltips[0].style.top = e.pageY + 'px';
}

bars[0].onmouseenter = () => {
  tooltips[0].style.display = 'flex';
}
bars[0].onmouseleave = () => {
  tooltips[0].style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
.tooltip {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">
  <p>Rect 1</p>
</div>

<svg width="500" height="500">
    <rect width="200" height="30" x="0" y="0" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255)" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because when the tooltip is opened, it will come over the mouse. And `mouseleave` for rect is triggered, and tooltip closes and mouseenter is triggered again. So it goes into an infinite loop. We can use `pointer-events: none` to avoid mouse events on tooltip.

```js
const tooltips = document.querySelectorAll('.tooltip');
const bars = document.querySelectorAll('rect');

document.addEventListener('mousemove', fn);

function fn(e) {
  tooltips[0].style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
  tooltips[0].style.top = e.pageY + 'px';
}

bars[0].onmouseenter = () => {
  tooltips[0].style.display = 'flex';
}
bars[0].onmouseleave = () => {
  tooltips[0].style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
.tooltip {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: grey;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">
  <p>Rect 1</p>
</div>

<svg width="500" height="500">
    <rect width="200" height="30" x="0" y="0" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255)" />
</svg>
```

Another way, you can push the tooltip a little further away from the mouse. I used `e.pageX + 5` and `e.pageY + 5` for example.

```js
const tooltips = document.querySelectorAll('.tooltip');
const bars = document.querySelectorAll('rect');

document.addEventListener('mousemove', fn);

function fn(e) {
  tooltips[0].style.left = (e.pageX + 5) + 'px';
  tooltips[0].style.top = (e.pageY + 5) + 'px';
}

bars[0].onmouseenter = () => {
  tooltips[0].style.display = 'flex';
}
bars[0].onmouseleave = () => {
  tooltips[0].style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
.tooltip {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">
  <p>Rect 1</p>
</div>

<svg width="500" height="500">
    <rect width="200" height="30" x="0" y="0" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255)" />
</svg>
```